# Form passes attribute which is not part of the model as param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters, controller

I have a form with a drop down list of currency values, for example:

["Free", "$1", "$2"]

The result is passed to the controller as the parameter :donation. But I need to convert this string (example "$1"), to an integer so I can save it in the model in attribute :donation_per_ticket.

The value from the drop down is being passed to the controller. But it doesn't work when I try to use it with something like this in the controller:

```
@ticket.donation_per_ticket = ["Free", "$1", "$2"].index(params[:donation])
```

Through troubleshooting, I've realized that params[:donation] is nil, not "$1". Am I trying to reference the parameter incorrectly or is the parameter ignored by the controller?

I'm using ruby on rails 4 and I'm using the simple_form gem to create the form.

**Log from development**

```
Started POST "/performances/15/tickets" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-16 14:41:25 -0500
Processing by TicketsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xh4h5PKgjjE8hKv0NxXwoBMui6nNB9Wf9ecfMh/1eaU=", "ticket"=>{"performance_id"=>"", "user_id"=>"1", "status"=>"pending", "access_key"=>"9dfd37c27d6994e919e587fbe087d345", "name"=>"jjj", "email"=>"info@undertheguntheater.com", "quantity"=>"1", "donation_per_ticket"=>"$12"}, "commit"=>"Reserve tickets", "performance_id"=>"15"}
  Performance Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "performances".* FROM "performances"  WHERE "performances"."id" = ?  ORDER BY start_time ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 15]]
  Show Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "shows".* FROM "shows"  WHERE "shows"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY full_name ASC LIMIT 1
Unpermitted parameters: donation_per_ticket
  Performance Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "performances".* FROM "performances"  WHERE "performances"."id" = ?  ORDER BY start_time ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 15]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 220ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/tickets_controller.rb:67:in `create'
```

Comment: What actually do you need? - you need to convert selected value to int?

Comment: Did you permit the `:donation` parameter in your controller?

Comment: When I added :donation to the list of permitted parameters, it threw an error since it's not an actual attribute of Tickets.

Comment: @KevinM can you post your logs? You can also handle it on client side by js and strip "$" from value.

Comment: Which part of the log should I be looking for that you want to see, @Mandeep?

Comment: @KevinM when you submit your form. Also what are you trying to do by `@ticket.donation_per_ticket = ["Free", "$1", "$2"].index(params[:donation])`?

Comment: The array is used to populate the drop down list in the form. It just so happens that the index of the array corresponds to the value I actually want to store in :donation_per_ticket. So before I save the Ticket in the create action of the controller, I want to assign the index value to the :donation_per_ticket attribute of the Ticket.

Comment: @KevinM yeah figured it out after posting my comment :) Can you post your logs? I think i know what the problem is but need to see logs to be sure

Comment: I will add the log when I'm back at my development machine.

Comment: @KevinM no issues. Since you are sending donation value by a form so it would be nested inside form_for resource so you need to use something like this: `params[:form_for_resource][:donation]`

Comment: I'll try that as soon as I get back to the office. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't seem to work. I'll post the log.

Comment: @KevinM looking at logs the name of your field is `donation_per_ticket` so you can use `params[:ticket][:donation_per_ticket]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to render your dropdown so that the integer values are passed as the params, not the human-friendly values.

Since you mentioned you're using simple_form, you can do something like the following in your form:

```
<%= f.input :donation do %>
  <%= f.select :donation, [["Free", 0], ["$1", 1], ["$2", 2]] %>
<% end %>
```

which renders html as:

```
<select id="ticket_donation" name="ticket[donation]">
  <option value="0">Free</option>
  <option value="1">$1</option>
  <option value="2">$2</option>
</select>
```

and submits params as:

```
# log file
Parameters: {"ticket"=>{"donation"=>"1"}}
```

Comment: I came up with an alternative, but I like your solution better.